# How to fix TypeError: string indices must be integers in a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, integer

I am getting the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers How can I solve this issue?

The reason why I am doing this is so I can convert my dataframe into a huggingface dataset so I can develop a chatbot using transformers.

I have written a chatbot using dummy data from huggingface.co but I now I need to use my own data.

Please show proof that your answer works.

Dataframe:

| tag | patterns | response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| organized artist | Keep related supplies in the same area., | If you're a photographer, keep all the necessary lens, cords, and batteries |
| create neopoprealist art work | Create a sketch in the NeoPopRealist manner of the future mural on a small piece of paper x using the black ink pen., | See the image for how this drawing develops step by step. However, there is an important detail: |
| visual effects artist | Enroll in a studio based program., | It is possible to become a VFX artist without a college degree, but the path is often easier with one. |
| become art investor | Start with some experience or interest in art., | The best art investors do their research on the pieces of art that they buy, so someone with some education |
| organized artist | Keep your reference materials, sketches, articles, photos, etc, | As you start planning for a project or work, you'll likely be gathering scraps of inspiration and test sketches. |

My code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('wikihowAll.csv')
data = data.dropna()
data['clean_title'] = data['title'].map(lambda s:preprocess(s))
data['clean_headline'] = data['headline'].map(lambda s:preprocess(s))
data['clean_text'] = data['text'].map(lambda s:preprocess(s))
data['clean_title'] = data['clean_title'].astype(str)
data['clean_headline'] = data['clean_headline'].astype(str)
data['clean_text'] = data['clean_text'].astype(str)
data['title_clean_sent'] = data['title'].apply(clean)
data['headline_clean_sent'] = data['headline'].apply(clean)
data['text_clean_sent'] = data['text'].apply(clean)
data = data[['clean_title','headline_clean_sent','text_clean_sent']]
data.columns = ['tag', 'patterns', 'responses']
data['tag'] = data['tag'].astype(str)
data['patterns'] = data['patterns'].astype(str)
data['responses'] = data['responses'].astype(str)

intents = data.to_json(orient='records') 

new_collection = [] # store our reformed records
# loop over parsed json, and reshape it the way we want
for record in json.loads(intents):
    nested = {'intents': [record]} # matching specs of question
    new_collection.append(nested)
    
intents = json.dumps(new_collection) 

with open("myfile.json","w") as outfile:
    json.dump(intents, outfile)

data_file = open('myfile.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:

        #tokenize each word
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        #add documents in the corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))

        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 for intent in intents['intents']:
      2     for pattern in intent['patterns']:
      3 
      4         #tokenize each word
      5         w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How to resolve the error message. Please explain what I did wrong and how to fix it.

I was told to put the full code in the question I am asking. I would like to understand how to save the json file without the error message.

Comment: `intents` is a string. Without providing the data you will have to debug it yourself.

Comment: I can't provide the data.  The site won't let me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a double-encoding into JSON.

With the line

```
intents = json.dumps(new_collection)
```

you write the json structure `new_collection` into a string, the string is stored in `intents`. E.g., if your python structure was `{ 'a': [ 1, 2 ] }`, the string will be the JSON encoded version of that python structure: `"{"a": [1, 2, 3]}"`.

With the next block,

```
with open("myfile.json","w") as outfile:
    json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

you write that string, encoded as JSON, to the file. String is a JSON datatype, it gets encoded by escaping characters that would break the JSON code: `"{\"a\": [1, 2, 3]}"`.

With

```
data_file = open('myfile.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)
```

you read that JSON file again, decode it from JSON and get your string back, the string representation of a JSON encoded structure, *not* the structure itself.

So with the dumps and dump sequence, you double-ecode the structure, hence to solve this, get rid of the `intents = json.dumps(new_collection)` and just use that `new_collection` directly in the dump method to write it into a file.